# How can I see the structure of the output of a flake.nix after passing the input as argument?

Tags: nix

This code take the inputs of a `flake.nix` and give it to the function outputs.

```
let repo = fetchGit { url = "https://github.com/informalsystems/cosmos.nix"; }; 
in with repo; 
let cosmos = import "${repo}/flake.nix"; 
in cosmos.outputs { inputs = cosmos.inputs; }
```

```
error: attribute 'flake-utils' missing
       at /nix/store/ad5kdvzjqy2m4h1alm6amx7mgyzm8463-source/flake.nix:150:10:
          149|   outputs = inputs:
          150|     with inputs.flake-utils.lib;
             |          ^
          151|       eachSystem
```

There is a flake-utils in the input. I don't understand the error.

By the way, is there any built-in function doing exactly the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With versions of Nix new enough to have built-in flake support, the expression you want is:

```hs
builtins.getFlake "github:informalsystems/cosmos.nix"
```

...which will return an attrset with inputs, outputs, packages, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `outputs` is a function that takes one argument and expects it to be a set with an attribute named `flake-utils`.  But instead of passing such a set to it, you constructed a new set that only has one attribute, and the name of that attribute is `inputs`, not `flake-utils`.  You constructed that undesired set here: `{ inputs = cosmos.inputs; }`.

You can get a little bit further with this expression, but then note that this expression failed because `flake-utils.lib` is missing:

```
let
  repo = fetchGit { url = "https://github.com/informalsystems/cosmos.nix"; };
  flake = import "${repo}/flake.nix";
in flake.outputs flake.inputs
```

Answer (score 0):

a little improvement of Charles Duffy answer.

in bash:

```
 nix-instantiate --eval -E 'let flake = builtins.getFlake "github:informalsystems/cosmos.nix"; in let possible_choice= flake.outputs.packages.${builtins.currentSystem}; in  possible_choice.the_field_you_want_to_see'
```

or directly in nix reply

```
let 
  flake = builtins.getFlake "github:informalsystems/cosmos.nix";
  possible_choice= flake.outputs.packages.${builtins.currentSystem}; 
 in  possible_choice.the_field_you_want_to_see
```

I've given these 2 different way because the way the result is printed is not exactly the same.

With this code you see only the package but if you replace package by devshells, you see all the devshells.

Comment: I think you never need to write `in let`, like that, you can just have a `let` expression that defines two variables.  The variables can refer to each other in their definitions.

Comment: @DAvidGrayson I've change the text now. Thanks